# Linker Error PPC

Tags: macos, c++11

I'm trying to compile a c++11 code under a IBook G4.

I'm using a `g++-4.9` installed with `brew`

However, I get stuck with this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: can't locate file for: -lcrt0.o
```

Found nothing in the net about `crt`. Maybe, someone has better experience dealing with *dinosaurs*..

Comment: what os are you running? not many people are going to be running g++-4.9 on PPC macs, I suspect you will run into more problems

Comment: Mac OS X version 10.4.11 I know it is not a brand new one, but still I would like to compile C++11 on that one.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0

Comment: I was just thinking about this, you could install ppc Linux and run that... There are just so many issues with c++11 and libstdc++ and libc++ and backwards comparability... You really do need to be on a modern system.

Comment: I just reinstalled Mac and tried to install ONLZ brew packages. There is a GCC 4.9 there, but the linker can not find that Crt0 thing. Should be doable. I will give it a try in the week end. Otherwise, linux on ppc sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Frustration of having a compiler able to run on multiple architectures with the flip of a command line switch.  Use -arch and specify either native or target cpu.